# How can I make the min-height of my menu the same as my header?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have this issue on smaller screens. I want my menu to be 100% height and 100% width - 25px margin on all side. The probleem is when someone has a small screen I can see the header content(text) under my menu because of my 25px botton margin. Is there a way I can fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/vh2zugku/1/

```
position: absolute;
top: 25px;
right: 25px;
left: 25px;
z-index: 1;
height: calc(100% - 50px);
margin: auto;
color: white;
background: $Black;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

This may look strange but pls play with the height and see what I mean.

Comment: Is it possible to use a border of the same color as the body background?  You could have the appearance of spacing, but it's would be just a border.

Comment: Uhm, good point, I will try it now.

Comment: Ok that worked great... I am stupid. Anyway Is there away I can block people from scrolling? They can still scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the background is a solid color, you could just use a border instead of a gap.  Just make sure the border is the same color as the document background.

This would look like something along the lines of:

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* height is removed but you could set it to 100% */
  border: 25px solid #F3F5F6;
  ...
}
```

Also, in lieu of another comment on the question itself, [here is a quick fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zoaue8kq/) that sets a body class when the menu is opened and removes it when it closes.  (This is in response to your comment above.)  This class sets the body to `position: fixed`.  It prevents scrolling.  You could also use `overflow:hidden` on the body to achieve a similar effect.